# Spark context for the thrift server

Tags: apache-spark

Does every jdbc connection to apache spark thrift server create a seperate spark context? If the answer is "No", how to create a seperate spark context for every JDBC connection to thrift server.

Comment: Generally speaking Spark supports only one SparkContext per JVM. See [SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243).

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Context in thrift server is just one.
Spark Thrift server is not suitable for high concurrent application access.